# How do I solve getting stuck issue of two nested for loops?

Tags: c#, performance, for-loop

I have coded a C# Windows Form Application where there are **two nested for loops** like below:

```
List<int> My_LIST = new List<int>();

List<string> RESULT_LIST = new List<string>();
int[] arr = My_LIST.ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    int counter = i;
    for (int j = 1; j <= arr.Length; j++)
    {
        if (counter == arr.Length)
        {
            counter = 0;
        }

         sb.Append(arr[counter].ToString());
         RESULT_LIST.Add(sb.ToString());
         counter++; 
     }

    sb.Clear();
}
```

I used this code to take any combination of characters that are inside my array.

When the array's length gets 3000 or more the program gets stuck. How can I fix this issue?

Because based on my application's needs the size of my array must be large.

First, I had used a normal **string** to get the combinations and my code was like below:

```
string s = "";
```

instead of this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
```

I thought that there may be a problem with the normal string's maximum length and therefore I changed it to `StringBuilder` but the problem was not fixed.

Is this problem solvable or I should use an alternative?

Comment: You will need to use a Task or a Thread for this, because your code takes too much to compelte so the main thread (which is your GUI's thread) blocks until your operations are done.

Comment: `sb.ToString()` needs to allocate a new `string` each time it's called. That's not the intended usage of a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @Haitam I see, but my problem is not UI's getting stuck issue. after a specific array length near to 3000 or more the program gets stuck. In order to see whether I am right or not I put a progressBar and defined its maximum value as n*n and used the code `progressBar.Value++;` and after a specific length the progressBar's value is not increasing.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto The problem is not string or StringBuilder, What I want to fix is the applications stopping issue. Even if I use the StringBuilder not properly it shouldn't get stuck. Am I wrong bro?

Comment: There is an array with different characters inside it I need to find out any combinations of the characters inside it to see whether there is a message in it or not?

Comment: You are not wrong, but it will lead to high memory usage sooner or later.

Comment: Given your last comment, please add example input and expected output. There might be far better solutons

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yeah, You're absolutely right. But I have no other alternatives. At least I think I don't have.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto What do you exactly mean? I haven't made the first array it has been entered by another user and the scenario says that you don't know whether there is a message in the array or not, and if there is we don't know the location.

Comment: According to my test the memory usage is 3GB for 1000 items. You have to redesign your program to avoid so huge allocations if you want to get higher.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek I don't think that I have an alternative, Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It depends on why you need it. You want to save it to the file? Perfect, just save it and do not store it in memory. You want to iterate through it? Nice, just make IEnumerable and not store it all in the memory.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek Amazing Solutions, But don't you think writing line to line to a text file or any other file time can take a lot of time?

Comment: You need to describe in plain words what problem you are solving. This code is _very_ strange, I really don't have a clue just from code what is the goal. There is high chance that your problem can be solved differently.

Answer (score 3):

your program is not getting stuck, rather it's taking a long time to finish due to it only running on a single thread.

you may want to use [Parallel.For](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-for-loop) which its iterations can run in parallel.

I would first suggest parallelising the outer for loop and then test if there are any performance improvements if not then also parallelise the inner loop. In the majority of cases parallelising the outer for loop can prove sufficient.

---

Also, note that using a `StringBuilder` as an accumulator and then performing  `sb.Append(arr[counter].ToString());` inside the loop is *sub-optimal*. Don't call `toString` at all, just append.

However, when performing parallel processing keep in mind that `StringBuilder` **is not thread-safe**, therefore, you're better off using a `String` rather than trying to introduce locking or anything of that sort to retain the `StringBuilder`.

Finally, you'll need to be cautious in regards to *shared state*, and therefore I'd recommend you do some research in terms of what to take into account when performing parallel processing.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You were right there was no need for `.ToString();`